# Setting objects as partners within the same class in java

Tags: java, object, constructor, program-entry-point, setter

As a task in my beginners course in object oriented programming, I must set two objects in my `Partner` class as "married".

This is my attempt at beginning:

```
public class Partner {

  String name;
  String partner;



  public Partner(String name, String partner) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.partner = partner;
  }

  public String getPartner() {
    return partner;
  }

  public void setPartner(Partner()) { //think i need the object here?
    this.partner = partner;         //however i don't know how
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Partner p1 = new Partner("Name1", idk);
    Partner p2 = new Partner("Name2", idk);

  }

}
```

My issue is that I don't know how to use the object in the `setPartner` method, if that's even the correct way to do it. It should also be possible to get a divorce from the other object by setting one of the objects' partner to `null`.

It should also make it so that the partners automatically register as married to eachother if one of them is set a married to the other. For example, if p1 is set as the partner of p2, p2 should automaticly be set as the parter to p1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two constructors: one with just `name` and another with `name` and `partner` (of type, `Partner`) so that you will have the flexibility to initialize an object with just name and then set its partner or initialize with name and partner (if the partner is known).

```
public class Partner {

    private String name;
    private Partner partner;

    public Partner(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Partner(String name, Partner partner) {
        this.name = name;
        setPartner(partner);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPartner(Partner partner) {
        partner.partner = this;
        this.partner = partner;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String value;
        if (partner != null) {
            value = name + ", partner=" + partner.name;
        } else {
            value = name;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example 1
        Partner p1 = new Partner("Name1");
        Partner p2 = new Partner("Name2");
        p1.setPartner(p2);
        System.out.println(p1);
        System.out.println(p2);

        // Example 2
        Partner p3 = new Partner("Name3");
        Partner p4 = new Partner("Name4", p3);
        System.out.println(p3);
        System.out.println(p4);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name1, partner=Name2
Name2, partner=Name1
Name3, partner=Name4
Name4, partner=Name3
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can make it so that p1.setPartner(p2) sets p1 as partner to p2 as well? Basically saying that p1.setPartner(p2) should run p2.setPartner(p1) without writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to write setter methods ? Something like this

```
    public void setPartner(String partner) {
        this.partner= partner;
    }
```

Comment: No, but I'm almost certain that the setter should be in the ballpark of "setPartner(Partner)". I'm not even sure if the String partner is needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you intend for a `Partner` object to have a pointer to another object of this class, you should change `String partner` to `Partner partner`.
2. You won't always have an initialized `Partner` object to use in the `Partner` constructor, so you have 3 options:

   - add another constructor which doesn't require an argument of type `Partner`
   - change the existing constructor
   - pass `null` as argument.
     In any case, you'll have to initialize the `partner` field somewhere else.
3. That's where setters come in. The correct syntax for your `setPartner` function would be:

   ```
   public void setPartner(Partner partner) {
     this.partner = partner;
   }
   ```

   `getPartner()` function should be changed accordingly to return the correct type.
4. Your code in `main()` can then be something like this:

   ```
   Partner p1 = new Partner("Name1", null);
   Partner p2 = new Partner("Name2", p1);
   p1.setPartner(p2);
   ```
5. > It should also be possible to get a divorce from the other object by setting one of the objects' partner to null.

   That is accomplished by using `p.setPartner(null)`, where `p` is an object of type `Partner`. You might also want to set both objects `partner`s to null instead of just one, for easier checking.

Comment: Thank you! I have now managed to set an object's partner, however, it does not automatically set the other object as partner as well. For example; p2.setPartner(p1) does not set a partner for p1, only for p2. Do you have any idea as to why? Also, when my toString consists of null it crashes the program. How to I work around that?

Comment: @alleElskeEtComeback If you want to set `partner` for both objects with one `setPartner()` call, you should add `partner.setPartner(this)` to the `setPartner()` function. That way it will be setting the `partner` field of both objects. As for crashing, you can just check if it points to null (e. g. `if (p == null)`), and return an appropriate string.

Comment: How would the setter look then? If I just add it as it's own line after this.partner = partner it creates a recursive error.

Comment: @alleElskeEtComeback You can check if `partner.getPartner() != this`, and call `partner.setPartner(this)` only if that statement is true.